# type traits specialization

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<typename T>
class vec3
{
public:
    typename T type_t;
    T x;
    T y;
    T z;
};

template<typename T>
struct numeric_type_traits_basic_c
{
    typedef T type_t;
    typedef T scalar_t;
};

template<typename T>
struct numeric_type_traits_vec3_c
{
    typedef T type_t;
    typedef typename T::type_t scalar_t;
};

typedef numeric_type_traits_basic_c<int> int_type_traits;
typedef numeric_type_traits_vec3_c< vec3<int> > vec3_int_type_traits;
```

This is type traits for scalar and vector, the only difference is that the scalar type, for a  vector, is the type of its element. Works fine.

But I'd really like to be able to use the same name for those two classes.

```
template<typename T>
struct numeric_type_traits_c
{
    typedef T type_t;
    typedef ????? scalar_t;
};
```

I know this is possible to do so if the class is explicitly specialized for each type I need: int, float, vec3, vec3...

That's a lot of duplication... How can I keep the simplicity of the first bit of code but have the same class name at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the syntax for partial class template specialisation:

```
template<typename T>
struct numeric_type_traits // basic template
{
    typedef T type_t;
    typedef T scalar_t;
};

template<typename T>
struct numeric_type_traits< vec3<T> > // partial specialisation for vec3's
{
    typedef vec3<T> type_t;
    typedef T scalar_t;
};
```

And so on, e.g.:

```
template <typename T, typename T_Alloc>
struct numeric_type_traits< std::vector<T,T_Alloc> > // part. spec. for std::vector
{
    typedef std::vector<T,T_Alloc> type_t; // deal with custom allocators, too
    typedef T scalar_t;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should instantiate your template with two types? See:

```
template<typename TYPE, typename SCALAR>
struct numeric_type_traits_c
{
   typedef TYPE type_t;
   typedef SCALAR scalar_t;
};

typedef numeric_type_traits_c<int,int> int_type_traits;
typedef numeric_type_traits_c<vec3<int>, vec3<int>::type_t> vec3_type_traits;
```

Comment: The intention behind type trait is to avoid that as the type trait is exatly suppose to provide you with such information

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T>
struct numeric_type_traits_c
{
        typedef T type_t;
        typedef T scalar_t;
};

template<typename T>
struct numeric_type_traits_c<vec3<T> >
{
        typedef vec3<T> type_t;
        typedef typename vec3<T>::type_t scalar_t;
};
```

Yes, for sure I've made a mistake in type_t for vec3!

Answer (score 0):

An interesting remark here lies in applying the knowledge we have from dynamic polymorphism to  the 'type function' polymorphism.

If you compare this function f:

```
struct I { virtual double f()const = 0; }; // C++ version of 'an interface'
struct A : public I { virtual double f()const{ return 0; } };
struct B : public I { virtual double f()const{ return 1; } };
struct C { };

void f( const I& i ){ return I.f(); }

f( A() );
f( C() ); // compiler warning: wrong type provided.
```

with this function f:

```
// struct TI { typedef ??? iT; }; // no C++ version of a type-interface
struct TA { typedef int iT; };
struct TB { typedef double iT; };
struct TC { };

template< typename aTI > struct fT { typedef aTI::iT returnType; };

fT< TA >::returnType vA; 
ft< C  >::returnType vC; // compiler error: C has no iT member.
```

You see that the only difference is the notation of the parameters.  The first function is a 'regular' polymorphous function.  The compiler will warn us if the provided argument is not of the proper type.

fT is a function that can only be used by the compiler to determine a certain type.  It takes a type as argument.  But the language has no "concept" of a type-constraint (yet - see Concepts in C++0x).  So we need to hand-guarantee that the types we use for a type-function 'implement' the correct interface.

In concreto, this boils down to adding the `scalar_t` type to any class you want to use with the `numeric_type_traits_c` type function.